# Using an iPhone 6s from USA in Europe

Tags: iphone, lte

I'll soon visit US where I want to buy an iPhone 6s (money reasons).My question is: will I be able to use it properly (full capacity) in Europe (Romania)? I read a couple of topics and found out there are problems related to LTE bands and others but I don't understand it yet.

Comment: On Apple's website, it says the LTE bands of different models of iPhones. You'll want to check with your carrier to see what LTE bands they use and if the US iPhone uses one of those bands. Or if you go to apple.com and choose the Buy iPhone button, it'll take you to a shopping page and there'll be an option to chat with support, they will have the info.

Answer (score 1):

When I traveled to the EU with my iPhone 6s having Verizon service on it, it worked perfectly fine there since it's a world phone.
Although verifying with your carrier would be the ideal thing since carriers could have rules of not accepting phones not branded by them and also to verify for 100% that the LTE bands are correct for their network but as far as operation wise I could confirm that I used my iPhone 6s in the EU back in March.